# Regex don't match if URI contains extension

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm getting stuck on a bit of regex, needed in an htaccess file on an old project I've taken on. I want to match the following uris

```
/page?id=12
/admin/users-view?id=3242
/subscribe
```

Where there may or may not be a query string, and may or may not be multiple segments

I need to insert a `.php` extension, before the query string. So the first example becomes

```
/page.php?id=12
```

I also cannot match any uri with a file extension, so that images, js or css files do not get matched.

I came up with this:

```
^([/\w-]+)?/?
```

which does what i need apart from the last point. My regex skills are poor, so any help is appreciated

Comment: I've added `.htaccess` tag so it is clear now. ;)

Comment: BTW, regex in m.buettner's solution  should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to think about disassembling the URL with `parse_url` and putting it back together after manipulation.

However, for a pure regex solution, I think I would try to find a string starting at a slash (or the beginning of the string) and a question mark that does not contain periods:

```
$url = preg_replace('~(^|/)[^.?]*(?=[?]|$)~', '$0.php', $url);
```

The `parse_url` solution would rather look like:

```
$urlParts = parse_url($url);
if(pathinfo($urlParts['path'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === null)
    $urlParts['path'] .= '.php';
$url = implode($urlParts);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I failed to mention that I need to use this in an htaccess file, so can't use parse_url

Comment: This is so close, however it doesn't match if there is no query string. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

dont parse URIs with regexp, php has built in functions for that

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

note, there is also reverse function which builds url:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php

you should use them instead of regexp because they will (at least should) handle url encoding correctly

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained a bit more, this is for use in an .htaccess file, so I don't have a choice

Comment: No problem, I was mislead by "php" tag :)